How do you diagnose a fault with a tweeter?
I have a Pioneer XPRS 10 at work that isn't producing any high frequencies; the 10" woofer working fine, but the 1.75" tweeter is not producing any sound at all. It's a 50W, 8 ohm tweeter. I have tried it on a couple of amplifier outputs. What's really strange is that it tests fine in other areas: it shows up as 6.5 ohm resistance on a multimeter, which I understand is normal on DC. When I do the 'battery test' on the terminals with an AA battery, the tweeter crackles and shows signs of life. The dome/diaphragm itself also looks completely intact.
Though my job does occasionally involve fixing audio equipment, I'm an amateur at fixing speakers, and all my knowledge is gleaned from the internet + some years experience of messing around with electronics. How do I go about diagnosing what the real problem is? If the diaphragm is fine, what other parts of a tweeter can go wrong?

The passive crossover inside the speaker could be banjaxed. It will be high-pass, so there's probably an inline capacitor.

So it's likely not the speaker itself that is at fault, but the end of the amplifier chain? I'll investigate by opening up the amplifier circuit when I get back. Thanks

No, for passive speakers the crossover is inside the speaker cabinet as stated in my previous comment. https://blog.teufelaudio.com/what-is-a-speaker-crossover/

Cheers for the link. It's not passive, it's active. Pioneer XPRS 10
